# What are all the query parameters for getEntityRecords?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, documentation

I'm working on a plugin that defined a custom block for the Gutenberg/Block Editor. The block shows a `select` box of posts. When you select one, I create HTML with some of the selected post's fields, such as title, date, etc.

When I query my posts in the `edit` method, my code correctly produces a list of pages (in my case, a custom post type named `product`), but custom fields, which this post type has, are not included.

```
var pages = select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'product', { per_page: -1 });
```

I'm trying to find documentation on `getEntityRecords` query parameters, but there seems to be none. Is it possible to include custom fields in the query? You would think this should be explained on https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/data/data-core/#getentityrecords

My only other idea was: when the block is saved ("during" the `save` method), is it possible to do another query that just selects the single post by ID and retrieves its data, maybe including custom fields? It seems I can't query anything during save.

Answer (score 17):

If you look into the source code for `getEntityRecords`, you'll see that the the `core/data` library creates entities using the Wordpress API in [entities.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/core-data/src/entities.js).

So you can use any parameter available in the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/). Here are options for posts:

```
context
page
per_page
search
after
author
author_exclude
before
exclude
include
offset
order
orderby
slug
status
categories
categories_exclude
tags
tags_exclude
sticky
```

Answer (score 6):

Gutenberg documentation is not finished yet, but there are some unreleased commits in the official Gutenberg Repo. This could help: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/b7ad77d15f32ca234ff2f3df4994e47a5cf2e6d7/packages/editor/src/components/page-attributes/README.md

```
[...]
    var query = {
            per_page: -1,
            exclude: postId,
            parent_exclude: postId,
            orderby: 'menu_order',
            order: 'asc',
            status: 'publish,future,draft,pending,private',
        };
        return {
            parentItems: isHierarchical ?
                selectCore.getEntityRecords( 'postType', postTypeSlug, query ) :
                []
        };
[...]
```