# Bulk Update Post Meta Values from Different Post via Rest Api

Tags: post-meta, rest-api

When I edit a custom post type in the Block Editor, I have successfully added a post meta (featured toggle button) in the Gutenberg Sidebar. When saving the post, I want to do two things:

1. save the post meta of the current post to either true or false.
2. I want to remove (or update to false) the same post meta keys in all existing custom post types (only if post meta for the current post is set to true).

However, I am failing at this one. I am able to update one additional custom post type by hardcoding its post id but i want to bulk update all the post metas and leave only the post meta from the current post to true. Is there a way around this query:

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    register_post_meta( 'guides', '_awg_featured_guide', [
        'auth_callback' => '__return_true',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'boolean',
    ] );
```

**featured-button.js**

```
    // Fetch data
    withSelect((select) => {
        return {
            otherPostMeta: select('core').getEntityRecord('postType', 'guides', 2160),
            postMeta: select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta'),
            postType: select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType(),
        };
    }),
    // Update data
    withDispatch((dispatch) => {
        return {
            setPostMeta(newMeta) {
                /* if post meta value in the current post is set to true, select all guides that contain the post meta _awg_featured_guide set to true and get rid of these values */
                dispatch('core').editEntityRecord('postType', 'guides', 2160, {
                    meta: {
                        _awg_featured_guide: false,
                    },
                });
                /* save post meta for the current post*/
                dispatch('core/editor').editPost({
                    meta: newMeta
                });

            }
        };
    })
```

Comment: If there would only be one post (in each of those post types) that may be featured (at a time), i.e. have the meta *set to true*, how about using a custom option instead? So it will store the ID of the featured post, e.g. `featured_post_guides` for the "guides" CPT. I believe that it'll be easier than using post meta. But if you rather use post meta (or if there'd be 2 or more featured posts in a post type), then you might want to add a REST API endpoint which would query the featured posts in the different post types and delete the `_awg_featured_guide` meta for the found posts.

Comment: Or don't delete yet and just return the posts as a response, then update the meta via Gutenberg, e.g. `editEntityRecord()`.

Comment: I prefer using the post meta table. Is there a way to extend the getEntityRecords method to filter posts by post meta key and value? I am stumbling on this for hours. I found this thread but it also does not lead me to anything: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/328277/what-are-all-the-query-parameters-for-getentityrecords

Comment: Re:the extend thing. Via PHP, yes, there are hooks you can choose from, but are you sure you don't want to use a custom taxonomy instead? Because taxonomy queries are more performant and remember that terms don't have to be titles like 'Foo Bar' and instead they can be a 0 or 1, (or strings like) true or false, yes or no, etc. to represent a boolean. And filtering posts by taxonomy/terms is also easy via the REST API.

Comment: Re:my [answer there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/341937). Are you sure it or the [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) no longer working?

Comment: My mistake, the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341905/can-you-filter-posts-by-meta-key-with-the-getentitityrecords-selector/341937#answer-341937) is correct, I forgot to change the filter name with my custom post type. So it should be ```rest_guides_query```

Comment: I was thinking to go with the Options Api at the beginning but then I realised if I just store the post id, i would need another query to get all the post data and I thought it would be easier to do it with post meta, since here i have all the info. Turned out it was not, as I spent quite some time wondering why it is not working. I would be interested to see an example how this could be done, though.

Comment: @SallyCJ, I made this work but, honestly, I did not like the user experience of it and finally decided to reconsider and go with your number one proposed solution: store the ID of the featured post as an option. I actually see now it is much easier like that, should have gone that road from the beginning. Thank you for the advice.